How to create behavior on delayed retry?
We are using an NSB8 endpoint which sends commands from a service that uses deterministic message IDs on ASB (that is for a given business ID it will always use the same message ID - this is good because it offers free deduplication)
We are currently using SendOptions.CustomizeNativeMessage() to support using the same deterministic ID scheme while sending a message, however on delayed retry where the endpoint errors we want to change the message id.
Is there any way we can create a behavior to set the native MessageID property on the native ASB message to an ID of our choosing on delayed retry? IRecoverabilityContext doesn't appear to have anything that I can hook into.
Any help would be appreciated.


this is good because it offers free deduplication

And at the same time could hide more and cause even more damage. But ¯_(ツ)_/¯

IRecoverabilityContext doesn't appear to have anything that I can hook into.

Not sure what you mean with "hook into", but there's context.FailedMessage.Headers isn't there? I'm assuming it works for the message identifier, but I'm not 100% sure, because you should (almost) never ever, ever change the MessageId.
We offer support at Particular Software for customers via support@particular.net and on our website. It's often better to use those, as it allows for follow-up questions and more.

I get your concern and would much prefer a managed approach that allowed us to influence the ID scheme. Sadly you don't offer this and in big organisations like ours, we can't just say everything must use NSB. This wouldn't be a problem if the endpoint was idempotent, but its not. It has an imperfect anti corruption layer around an old legacy system that cannot be changed. We are using ASB deduplication - its my view that NSB shouldn't get in the way of this. I.e. it shouldn't be easier to implement an idempotent messaging endpoint on ASB SDK than it is on NSB - but I guess thats theoretical.

If we don't offer something, it's possible we don't offer it for a reason. But I can imagine if you're communicating with legacy systems, sometimes things need to be circumvented. We do have deduplication though via Outbox. There's also a community package available from one of our devs to deduplicate. Email us at support@particular.net to learn more, no characters left.

NServiceBus is a middleware framework. Like any other middleware framework, it's opinionated and leverages native features that have to align with the abstractions it provides. One of the abstractions is what a native Azure Service Bus service doesn't support—delayed retries. While there are immediate retries in the form of re-deliveries, the delayed retries feature doesn't exist yet. When it is added, and you can up-vote the feature request here to let the team know it's needed, then NServiceBus can provide the best of both worlds: delayed retries and native duplicate detection. Until then, NServiceBus has to ensure that the message ID is a random value to ensure its delayed retries abstraction is working correctly.
